# What does “be dialed in to someplace/somebody” mean？

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

> President-elect Donald J. Trump’s transition was in disarray on Tuesday, marked by firings, infighting and revelations that American allies *were blindly dialing in to* Trump Tower to try to reach the soon-to-be-leader of the free world.

After consulting some dictionaries, I can't yet get the exact meaning of "American allies *were blindly dialing in to* Trump Tower".

> be (or get) dialled in
>
> Be or become so focused that one is able to perform to the best of one's abilities:
>   ‘I didn't really get dialled in until the final qualifying session’

Does it mean they were blindly focusing on the president-elect's recent movements? But that's not "be dialed in to", but "be dialing in to". Could it mean "visit Trump Tower online"?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's the literal, original meaning from telephone use.

"...allies were blindly dialing in to Trump Tower..." means "...allies were calling whatever phone numbers they could find at Trump Tower..."

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the difference between "be dialed" and "be dialing".